# Request Timeout ( HTTP 408) : loadbalancer backed by ecs-fargate with nginx image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate

I am trying to create following infrastructure using terraform.
***LoadBalancer -> ECS-Service -> Fargate (nginx images, count=2)***

After applying terraform plan, I can see that a target groups shows two healthy targets. But when i try to access loadbalancer dns name from browser, I am getting request-timeout. Ping is also not working for lb dns name.

Loadbalancer is an non-internal application loadbalancer with security-group allowing all traffic on 80 port to all IPv4.

Need help.

Comment: Did you configure `LB` in public subnet? and did you tired to access the application from aws network to verify the LB working inside aws vpc network? `curl lb_dns` or do `nslookup lb_dns` from any ec2 machine with in the vpc

Comment: @Adiii That hint was good enough to get me through. Problem was with subnet which was private. After switching to public subnet it worked. Thanks a lot. You can convert that to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you configure LB in the public subnet? seems like it's in a **private subnet**, and did you tried to access the application from aws network to verify the LB working inside AWS VPC network?

```
curl lb_dns
```

or

```
nslookup lb_dns
```

from any ec2 machine within the VPC if that worked, its mean the LB in only reachable with in private subnet, **move LB to public subnet** and should work.